# How do I convert text value from a textbox to an integer?

Tags: python, function, spyder, flet

My assignment is to create a program to take 3 sides of a triangle and determine whether it is equilateral, isosceles, scalene, or not a triangle. There are 3 textboxes for the user to enter the lengths of the sides of the triangle, and a button to trigger its function. I keep getting errors when it goes to convert the user-inputted text to an integer or float. I'll copy my code below.

I expected it to convert the user-inputted text from the textboxes to integers in order to be able to compare them mathematically to determine the type of triangle.

Please let me know if I need to share more detail, this is the first time I've asked questions on here, though I've been reading for a couple of years.

```
import flet as ft

def main(page: ft.Page):

############ function ##################
def is_triangle(side1, side2, side3):
    side1 = float(side1.value);
    side2 = float(side2.value);
    side3 = float(side3.value);
    if side1 + side2 > side3 or side2 + side3 > side1 or side1 + side3 > side2:
        get_type(side1, side2, side3);
        return(get_type(side1, side2, side3))
    else: 
        return("Not a triangle");
        
def get_type(side1, side2, side3):
    if side1 == side2 and side2 == side3:
        return("The Triangle is equilateral")
    else: 
        side1!= side2 and side2!= side3 and side1!= side3;
        return("The Triangle is scalene");
        
        output_textField.value = f"{is_triangle()}"
    page.update()

############# page setup ################
page.title = "Triangle Type Identifier"
page.window_width = 700
page.window_height = 700
page.theme_mode = "light"
page.window_center()
page.vertical_alignment = ft.MainAxisAlignment.SPACE_EVENLY
page.horizontal_alignment = ft.CrossAxisAlignment.CENTER

########### page content ###############
title_text = ft.Text("Enter the length of each side of a triangle", color = "BLUE", size = 30)

########### input ###############
input1 = ft.Text("Enter side 1 of a triangle", color = "BLACK", size = 25)
side1 = ft.TextField(width = 100, height = 100, color = "BLACK", text_size = 20, text_align = "center")

input2 = ft.Text("Enter side 2 of a triangle", color = "BLACK", size = 25)
side2 = ft.TextField(width = 100, height = 100, color = "BLACK", text_size = 20, text_align = "center")

input3 = ft.Text("Enter side 3 of a triangle", color = "BLACK", size = 25)
side3 = ft.TextField(width = 100, height = 100, color = "BLACK", text_size = 20, text_align = "center")


############ button ###############
get_type_button = ft.ElevatedButton(
    content = ft.ResponsiveRow(
        [ft.Text("Get Type of Triangle", size = 20, text_align = "center")]
    ),
    width = 300, height = 100, bgcolor = "BLUE", color = "WHITE", 
    on_click = is_triangle(side1, side2, side3)
)

########### output ###############
output_text = ft.Text("Triangle Type", color = "BLACK", size = 25)
output_textField = ft.TextField(
    width = 100, height = 100, color = "BLACK", text_size = 20, text_align = "center"    
)

page.add(
    title_text, 
    input1, 
    side1, 
    input2, 
    side2, 
    input3, 
    side3, 
    get_type_button,
    output_text, 
    output_textField
)
ft.app(target = main)
```

This was as far as I got. I keep getting the following error.
I tried using "a, b, c" within function "is_triangle" and that got it to where
it'd open the window at least, but then it would say
'TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a real
number, not 'TextField'

---

Unhandled error processing page session : Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\agcqu\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flet_runtime\app.py", line 357, in on_session_created
session_handler(page)
File "c:\users\agcqu\cs120\3.4 lab_3_quigley_anna.py", line 55, in main
on_click = is_triangle(side1, side2, side3)
File "c:\users\agcqu\cs120\3.4 lab_3_quigley_anna.py", line 7, in is_triangle
side1 = float(side1.value);
ValueError: could not convert string to float:
"""

Answer (score 0):

I've never used Flet before but from what I can see you are passing in side1, side2 and side3 into the `is_triangle` function as if they are strings, but they are not. Those variables are being assigned to the output of the `ft.TextField()` constructor, meaning they are instances of the `TextField` class. Going by the [documentation](https://flet.dev/docs/controls/textfield/) of that class, you are meant to use
the `Textbox.value` property to refer to the textbox's text value.